# Holes in network security

Tags: security, network-monitoring

Ok I'm a noob on Linux. I set the ufw firewall cli and gui both to deny incoming allow out. I don't do torrents so I removed Transmission and the rdt clients as well. Today I'm looking at firewall logs and Transmission BitTorrent and Deluge are all bound to ports. The printer client and CUPS are bound too along with a Telenet. Would it break the OS if I totally removed all of the Torrent framework along with the printer hook ups. I don't have a printer. Also I would like to remove pulse audio. I don't like the fact that it's listening on network ports either. As of now I have them all blocked but getting rid of the problem would be great. Thanks   I'm paranoid because I got hacked on Windows.

Comment: One of the biggest holes is allowing websites to show ads.  The biggest hole is usually the person in front of computer.  Unless NSA or one of their friends are after you,  would not bother to much with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any of that, Ubuntu by default has a very sensible firewall configuration. The CUPS server only is used when printing jobs occur, personally I wouldn't suggest removing that. Pulseaudio is your audio frontend, without it you cannot hear anything. Removing Transmission should be fine, and I don't think Telnet is automatically installed, but don't quote me.

If you're really concerned about your security, checking out the `psad` and `fwsnort` programs in your `apt` repos should help provide defense. For Firefox, I'd use the default privacy tools alongside uBlock Origin and Privacy Badger. uBlock is widely used and Privacy Badger is made by the Electronic Frontier Foundation, a reputable company.